# How to create a table with iText so that all columns the same width regardless of content?

Tags: pdf, itext

I've written some C# code with iText to create a table that renders numbers from a data source.  The problem I'm having is that the table mostly contains single digit numbers, but occasionally, there may be a number like `100`, and when the PDF is rendered with `100`, the table is rendered with the column containing `100` wider and the abutting columns narrower.

I've made a design decision that I want the columns to all be the same width regardless of contents.  I've specified the width of the column using `Cell.SetWidth`, but I'm still not getting the result I want.

What do I need to do to ensure that a table cell is rendered a certain width regardless of its contents.

Below is sample code that renders three rows of 48 cells each.  I just want the cells rendered the same size regardless of content.  For now, it's okay if the text may spill outside of a call or get clipped, but my concern is to make the cells the same size.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using iText.Kernel.Geom;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Layout;
using iText.Layout.Borders;
using iText.Layout.Element;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\test2.pdf", FileMode.Create);            
            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(fs);
            PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
            pdfDocument.SetDefaultPageSize(PageSize.LETTER.Rotate());
            Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);
            document.SetMargins(18, 18, 18, 18);

            Table table = new Table(CreateRepeatingValueArray(48, 16f))
                .SetBorder(new SolidBorder(1));

            // Fill our array of values with all zeros, and then make one value 100 to
            // show how column widths are perturbed.
            var values = CreateRepeatingValueArray<byte>(48 * 3, 0);
            values[2] = 100;

            foreach (byte value in values)
            {                               
                Cell cell = new Cell(1, 1)
                    .Add(new Paragraph(Convert.ToString(value)))
                    .SetFontSize(9)
                    .SetWidth(16f)
                    .SetTextAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.CENTER);
                table.AddCell(cell);                
            }

            document.Add(table);
            document.Close();
        }        

        static T[] CreateRepeatingValueArray<T>(int length, T value)
        {
            List<T> list = new List<T>(length);
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i += 1)
            {
                list.Add(value);
            }
            return list.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution to this.  I create a `Paragraph` object to hold each number and then set the width of the `Paragraph` object.  This seems to be working great so far.